# how can i append to a stringbuilder on every item usinq linq

Tags: c#, linq, collections

i have a stringbuilder

```
Stringbuilder b = new StringBuilder();
```

and i want to take a collection and append a propertyname from every item in the collection using LINQ.  Is this possible.

something like this:

```
myCollection.Select(r=> b.Append(r.PropertyName);
```

(but this doesn't seem to work)

Comment: As for why it's not working, you'd still have to iterate over the query (remember, the result of a query method is a query object, *not* the results of the query). Since you'd have to iterate over it anyway, you may as well just use a simple `foreach` loop as Anthony suggests. It's best to reserve LINQ for querying data since that what is was designed for, avoid using it for inducing side effects.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This would work (even though it's a very round-about way of doing things) and would work on any `IEnumerable<string>`:

```
List<string> foo = new List<string>();
foo.Add("bar");
foo.Add("baz");
StringBuilder result = foo.Aggregate(new StringBuilder(), (a, b) => a.Append(b));
```

Adapted to your example:

```
StringBuilder result = myCollection.Aggregate(new StringBuilder(), (a, b) => a.Append(b.PropertyName));
```

Answer (score 5):

You don't need to force the issue here with using LINQ when a simple foreach statement will be plenty expressive and concise enough. However, if you want to use more functional-esque approach, you can always go for something more like `string.Join` which I believe uses a `StringBuilder` internally (but don't quote me on it). Such as

```
builder.Append(string.Join("", myCollection.Select(r => r.PropertyName)));
```

But really, of all the examples you might see, will they be any less verbose (or more readable) than

```
foreach (var item in myCollection) 
     builder.Append(item.PropertyName);
```

?

Answer (score 2):

I would write it as:

`String.Concat(myCollection.Select(r => r.PropertyName));`

Comment: I did not realize they expanded `String.Concat` to accept `IEnumerable<string>` in an overload. Learn something new everyday.

Answer (score 1):

Some collections support an "Each" extension method:

```
myCollection.Each(r => b.Append(r.PropertyName));
```

EDIT: on second look, maybe this isn't provided out of the box.  I was thinking of the "ForEach" method on the List<> class.  Anyway, you can write your own Each method pretty easily:

```
public static void Each<T>(this IEnumerable<T> items, Action<T> action)
{
    if (items == null) return;

    var cached = items;

    foreach (var item in cached)
        action(item);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
        List<string> words = new List<string>()
        { 
        "aaa",
        "aab",
        "aac",
        "aad",
        };

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        words.ForEach(a => sb.AppendFormat("Element {0}\n",a));
```